# On Huygens Inequality for a proof.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, holder-inequality

I have a proof of a complicated inequality in my book, which first does a little manipulation and after this step-
$$ (1+3x) \left(1+{8y\over x} \right) \left( 1+{9z\over y}\right) \left(1+{6\over z} \right) \geq 7^4 $$
It mentions the proof is finished by **Huygens Inequality**.
My question is that what is Huygens Inequality? I found documents related to trigonometry while searching for this inequality online, but unfit for the proof of this step.

Please explain me what this inequality is. Thanks!

Comment: First Google search result: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1642h1004522

Comment: @MartinR, I know, I saw. But someone commented that it is wrongly stated, so I am dubious.

Comment: You asked *“what is Huygens Inequality?”*.– If you already know what it is and have a specific question about it then please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @MartinR I said in the previous comment that I'm uncertain for its validity. I want an undoubted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Huygens's inequality it's just privet case of the Holder's inequality for $n$ sequences of the length two.

I think, it's better to use Holder in any case:

By Holder $$(1+3x) \left(1+{8y\over x} \right) \left( 1+{9z\over y}\right) \left(1+{6\over z} \right)\geq\left(1+\sqrt[4]{3x\cdot\frac{8y}{x}\cdot\frac{9z}{y}\cdot\frac{6}{z}} \right)^4=2401.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I got my answer. I see I got better at inequalities. It wasn't possible without your support!